# How to create a .csv so it gets open with a specific configuration in excel?

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I'm using this function to create a .csv from a numpy 2d array encoded in utf-8:

```
def to_csv(string, name):
    with open("CSV_" + str(name[:-4]) + ".csv", 'w', newline='') as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c, delimiter=',')
        for i in range(len(string)):
            for j in range(len(string[0])):
                writer.writerow(string[i][j])
            c.write("\n")
```

But I'd like this to be the output when opened with excel (the standard output when you use the inport data from a csv function in excel):

[image]

Instead, I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the “Get & Transform Data” feature from Excel to have more options for adjustments when loading CSV files, e.g. choose the delimiter:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

If you use the “Open File” way, you can use the Import Text Wizard to adjust.

Comment: But how would I do it within python?

Comment: Rewriting (and deleting) my previous comments for better understanding: once you loaded the CSV into Excel as in pic1, up you could save the table from Excel as CSV then open it with a text editor to check how your Excel composes this as CSV (and how it expects a CSV to be). Based on regional settings, sometimes a , is used as decimal separator. In such settings, Excel would use a ; as CSV delimiter per default instead of the , This might be one reason why your Excel did not open the CSV as expected, as it was looking for a ; to separate the columns.

Answer (score 0):

What is about using
`df.to_excel("filename.xlsx")`? In this case you will get file in .xlsx format, and it will be displayed as you want in Excel. Here is a link to get more details: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to convert everything to xlsx instead of XML

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df.to_excel('example.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```